# scope and selecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

and can't understand why my code is not work

i have next:
`people/index.html.erb` =>

```
  <% @people.each do |i| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= i.id %></td>
      <td><%= i.name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to i.country_id, root_path(:country_id => i.country_id) %></td>
      <td><%= i.state_id %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

people_controller:

```
  def index
    @people = Person.all
    @people = @people.by_country_id(params[:country_id]) if params[:country_id].present?
  end
```

in person.rb

```
scope :by_country_id, lambda { |x| where(:country_id => x) }
```

root :to => 'people#index'

i want, when i click in link_to, i received all people with country_id

in the output i have ...localhost:3000/?country_id=1001

```
NoMethodError in PeopleController#index 
undefined method `by_country_id'
```

where i mistake ?

Comment: This is not working as `@people = Person.all ` gives you array of the `Person` object and so you can't apply method `by_country_id` on Array and if you try to do so it will give you an error undefine method by_country_id for an array

Comment: yes i forgot this ( in first answer comment )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@people = @people.by_country_id(params[:country_id]) if params[:country_id].present?
```

To

```
@people = Person.by_country_id(params[:country_id]) if params[:country_id].present?
```

Comment: I have not seen, you're right =)  @people = Person.all change to Person.order('created_at DESC')... thn =)